# Are you allowed to buy clothing, electronics and personal things during Sefira for Sephardim?

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, sefirat-ha-omer

Are you allowed to buy clothing, electronics and personal things during Sefira for Sephardim?

Comment: Why not? Some prohibition on gift giving?

Answer (score 1):

Some have a minhag not to say Shehecheyanu during the period of Sefirat Haomer, and therefore, they don't buy new clothes or other items which would require saying Shehecheyanu.

From [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Sefirat_HaOmer#Making_Shehecheyanu):

> The accepted Sephardic minhag is to make Shehecheyanu as usual.[Maamer Mordechai of Rav Mordechai Eliyahu (Sefirat HaOmer #55)]

Therefore, there is no problem for Sefardim to buy clothing or any other items during sefira.

But the Yalkut Yosef says the following:

> It is preferable not to wear new clothing which would require one to make a Shehecheyanu during the Sefira, however, if there's a need one should do it on a Shabbat, at a Simcha of a Bar Mitzvah or Brit Milah.[Yalkut Yosef (Moadim pg 433)]

So it seems like we have a machloket here. For practical purposes, ask your rabbi.

Comment: If purchasing other items besides clothing would that be allowed according to Sephardim during Sefira?

Comment: Yes you're allowed to, as the problem with buying things, is saying shechianu. But the accepted minhag for sefardim as that one is allowed to say shechianu. Therefore there's no problem in buying anything during sefira. But as always, you should ask your rabbi instead of following the advice of a stranger in the internet.